# change color of uitableviewcell for selected cell in sectioned table

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have sectioned table view with check selection for each section(every section allows only single selection like radio button).

now what i want to do is i want to change the color of cell that user has selected(not for fraction of time color change with animation using selectedBackgroundView property of cell).

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when the user select a row

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

gets called. You may consider implement this method in your delegate.

Comment: @Saphrosit: Hi, but how would i get access to cell in didSelectRowAtIndexPath method?

Comment: `[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]` is the selected row. Then you'll decide if change backgroundColor, backgroundView or whatsoever

Comment: @Saphrosit: ok let me try that.

Comment: @Saphrosit : i got success, but had one problem : when i select one option in section it works file, but if i change my selection for same section previous section is still have effect i assign to my previous selected cell. i.e change color of cell text. so is there any way in didSelectRowAtIndexPath method i can get count of cell in perticular section of table?

Comment: Not sure I understand, do you mean `[tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section]` ?

Answer (score 18):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];
```

Comment: Hi, use cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];
instead of  cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];

Answer (score 5):

Use this code........

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
     UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
     cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
 }
```

Happy Coding....

Answer (score 2):

Use this in tableview didSelectRowAtIndexPath: delegate method

```
 cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want to change the selection style of a particular cell in the tableview then following code can help.. Put this in the `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method and make the necessary changes

```
// x is the numbered location of that particular cell appearing in table view
if(indexPath.row==x) 
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    // UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue or UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone
    cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change only the background when it is selected you have a view reserved for that in a cell:

```
UIView *selectionBackground = [[UIView alloc] init];

selectionBackground.backgroundColor = A_COLOR;

myCell.selectedBackgroundView = selectionBackground;
```

Where A_COLOR is a UIColor. You can set this in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Answer (score 0):

**A.** If your cell's color is set to transparent (clearColor) you can simply set `cell.selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor`.

For dynamic usage this can be done in `-tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` (you can change color each time user selects a row). Otherwise in `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` - either when you setup the cell (after dequeuing or creating - to allow color changes, for example, each time you call `reloadData`) or when you create the table (if it wasn't dequeued - mostly for persistent color values).

**B.** If your cell's color is not set to transparent - set color in `-tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` as mentioned in most other comments. But using this method, don't forget to restore color of previously selected row.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
[cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:55.0/255.0f green:255.0/255.0f blue:178.0/255.0f alpha:1]];
```